# Logando em Site via C#

Tags: c#, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# e preciso fazer o seguinte:
Preciso inicialmente entra em um site em uma página específica. Contudo é necessário iniciar uma sessão, não basta colocar o link direto da página de *login*. É necessário entrar na *Home page* do site e entra na área de *login*. Para isso preciso que minha aplicação entre no site e faca o *login*.

O site em questão é o https://www.ccee.org.br na parte de conteúdo exclusivo. Feito o *login* a página e redirecionada para solicitar uma senha que sera enviada ou por SMS ou por e-mail. Para isso a aplicação deveria entrar nesse nova página e executar o botão de enviar a senha via e-mail. Até então consegui fazer a aplicação logar no e-mail e pegar a senha, mas não consegui de forma alguma fazer os primeiros passos (entrar no site, logar e executar o botão de receber via e-mail). Pesquisei muito na internet, li muitos fóruns (inclusive aqui) e a melhor o opção que me apareceu foi utilizar o HTML *Agility Pack* (Estou utilizando o visual studio 2015 e a aplicação e console mesmo).

Comment: Stack Overflow não é um fórum.

Comment: Sua pergunta é de baixa qualidade. [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/216035/edit) sua pergunta adicionando detalhamento e implementação que você já tenteou fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode implementar sua solução utilizando Selenium WebDriver, que tem o foco em realizar testes automatizados, porém, como você deseja executar a ação de abrir navegador e ir clicando em alguns botões, esta solução poderá lhe servidr... 
Você pode ler mais aqui http://taketest.take.net/2015/12/10/selenium-webdriver-instalacao-configuracao-e-teste-inicial-com-c/